# SSAS MDX Multiple Criteria in Where Clause

Tags: ssas, mdx, where-clause

How do you add multiple criterias for different dimensions of a MDX where clause?

For example with a normal SQL query you can use AND or OR to add multiple criteria:

```
Select * From MyTable Where Col1 = 'A' AND Col2 'B'
```

I've tried the same in MDX and it's not working. For example:

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Amount] } ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY { (
        [Store].[Division].[Division].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Department].[Dept].[Dept].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Accounts].[Level 1].[Level 1].ALLMEMBERS  *
        [Years].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS 
    ) } ON ROWS 
FROM 
    [Finance]
WHERE 
    {[Years].[Year].&[2018]} AND
    {[Accounts].[Level 1].&[Sales]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building a tuple like:

```
WHERE 
([Years].[Year].&[2018],
[Accounts].[Level 1].&[Sales])
```